# How to change paypal subscription amount in php

Tags: php

I have two kind of user registration($50/year,$100/year) on my site

Now, suppose a user registers with $50 amount and takes the first registration... next few years his $50 per year were deducted as per the recurring payment of paypal. It is working fine.

Now, he wants to upgrade to $100 i.e second membership , so from next year his amount deduction should be $100... How to update paypal for this change in amount..

I don't want to redirect the user to paypal site

Can you please help me to do this ?

Comment: Related: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/modifying.html This would require the user to login to Paypal and confirm this.

Comment: After logging the user we are showing 2 check boxes with above options. User can uncheck that options. If user uncheck first option, then no need to pay $100 for next all years. User needs to pay only $50. If user uncheck second box, then no need to pay $50, needs pay only $100 for next all users. But I don't want to redirect the user to paypal site.

Comment: _“But I don't want to redirect the user to paypal site.”_ – so you want to change something very essential about their transaction, without having them confirm that explicitly with Paypal? Please take a moment and think about how shady that sounds from a user’s perspective – would you want just any site on the web to be able to do that with your Paypal subscriptions …? No of course you would not.

Comment: Actually, here Paypal will remember the money to needs to get money from buyer account and send to merchant account as user already selected the recurring option while registration. 
So every year merchant account will get $150 from user account. Here my requirement is when user uncheck the option means downgrade the option then I need to update money in the paypal site. So if user want to change his plan from $150 to $100 then merchant will get only $100 from user account. I hope you can help me now.

Comment: Can we do this using CURL?